# Refer to an object instance and free it

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

If I create multiple `TButton` objects with this routine:

```
procedure CreateButton;
begin
  Btn := TButton.Create(nil);
end;
```

Then, how can I refer to a specific object instance to free it using another method like:

```
procedure FreeButton;
begin
  Btn[0].Free;  //???
end;
```

Of course, this does not compile, but I think the question is clear: How do I declare `Btn`? And how do I free multiple instances?

Comment: Your question is incomplete. "How can I refer to a specific instance?" How are you storing reference? If you don't remember the reference somewhere, how can you refer to it. How do you want to identify it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make much sense to create a `TButton` anywhere that isn't part of a form (which your code does).

With that being said, in order to refer to it later to free it, you need to store a reference to it somewhere.

Since you're referring to "multiple buttons" and using array code in your delete routine, I think you're probably wanting to track an array of buttons. Here's an example of doing just that:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);   // Add via Object Inspector Events tab
  private
    { Private declarations }
    // Add these yourself
    BtnArray: array of TButton;
    procedure CreateButtons(const NumBtns: Integer); 
    procedure DeleteBtn(BtnToDel: TButton);
    procedure BtnClicked(Sender: TObject);  
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.DeleteBtn(BtnToDel: TButton);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Check each button in the array to see if it's BtnToDel. If so,
  // remove it and set the array entry to nil so it can't be deleted
  // again.
  for i := Low(BtnArray) to High(BtnArray) do
  begin
    if BtnArray[i] = BtnToDel then
    begin
      FreeAndNil(BtnArray[i]);
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Create 10 buttons on the form
  CreateButtons(10);
end;

// Called when each button is clicked. Assigned in CreateButtons() below    
procedure TForm1.BtnClicked(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Delete the button clicked
  if (Sender is TButton) then
    DeleteBtn(TButton(Sender));
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateButtons(const NumBtns: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Allocate storage for the indicated number of buttons
  SetLength(BtnArray, NumBtns);

  // For each available array item
  for i := Low(BtnArray) to High(BtnArray) do
  begin
    BtnArray[i] := TButton.Create(nil);              // Create a button
    BtnArray[i].Parent := Self;                      // Tell it where to display
    BtnArray[i].Top := i * (BtnArray[i].Height + 2); // Set the top edge so they show
    BtnArray[i].Name := Format('BtnArray%d', [i]);   // Give it a name (not needed)
    BtnArray[i].Caption := Format('Btn %d', [i]);    // Set a caption for it
    BtnArray[i].OnClick := BtnClicked;               // Assign the OnClick event
  end;
end;
```

If you put this code in a new blank VCL forms application and run it, you'll see 10 buttons ('Btn 0`through`Btn 9`) on a form. Clicking on a button will remove it from the form (and the array).

Comment: Child controls are destroyed during parent destruction - no need for the owner.

Comment: Yes, I did read what you wrote. The only difference between your two versions of `CreateButton` is that the second passes form as owner to button constructor. Then is says that there is no need to free the button. The form "will do the work" even if it is not the owner but parent of the button.

Comment: Looks like you are missing the point. That's fine, more lines of code to maintain.

Comment: ?? A single "Self" vs "nil" is "more code to maintain"? What answer are you reading? My second example **eliminates** the ``FreeButton` entirely, in favor of adding `Self` as the owner. Looks like I'm not the one missing the point here.

Comment: Your second example is not needed. By your argument, `FreeButton` is not required in your first example.

Comment: No need to become upset over another poster's opinion.

Comment: Not upset. :-) I write answers based in part on the apparent knowledge level of the person I'm writing the answer for; in this case, I thought it was better to provide two separate code examples to clarify things. I really don't need to justify the reason I did that (or even explain it), and I'm certainly not going to justify every single character I typed because you're quibbling over (IMO) needless detail. If I were posting an answer to someone with more advanced knowledge of Delphi, I'd probably have phrased it differently.

Comment: I agree. Let them think that control must have an owner in order to be automatically destroyed.

Comment: @Igor: The point is not whether or not it is needed, the point is that passing Self makes the intention of the code that much clearer. Especially since there was a time that the form only freed owned controls. Freeing of parented controls wasn't part of the forms work for a long time. Avoiding confusion is always to be preferred over relying on changing behaviour of a framework.

Comment: @MarjanVenema - Could you, please, specify the last version of Delphi, in which `TWinControl` was not destroying its child controls in its destructor.

Comment: @Igor: No, because I don't intend to get into any sort of tit-for-tat argument over details with you. My point was made. If you don't like it, so be it.

Comment: @Igor: No, make it so that the **new** Delphi programmer isn't worried about that at all. Explicitly assigning `Owner` reminds them that they don't have to free it when they read the code in two weeks, because it reminds them the owner will do so (and it hurts nothing from a readability or maintenance standpoint). Is there a particular reason you're obsessing over this so much? Assigning owner here doesn't make a bit of difference to the code's function or maintainability, so it seems to just be a "might attract nitpickers" thing. But see my edited code, anyway.

Comment: Does a control really destroy its children when it is destroyed? I didn't know that.

Comment: @Igor The fact that parents destroy their children isn't well known, but more important: we should not need to! It's just a safeguard implementation in the VCL, and it isn't at all only a little bit semantic. The owner is responsible for destruction; that's what's in its name, and that's what an owner needs to do. The only situation wherein you could rely on destruction by parent is when the parent changes over time, e.g. when you move a control to another form. But even then, the Parent property could also be assigned nil, leaving the control unowned. Always make use of ownership.